# How to optimize coding numbers game?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

I want to construct a number with given 6+ inputs.

For example if i want to achieve number **280** with inputs **[2,4,5,10,30,50,66]** i want it to return a string like this: ((2+5) * 4 * 10). I can use input numbers only one time per solution. I wrote a code which basically does;

1- Store all possible subsets of given inputs.

2- Generate all possible permutations of the operators(Based on subset length their length is changed.So that it can form a valid expression)

3- Then concat the subsets with a valid permutation of operators. Then permutate that again with heap's algorithm.

4-Convert the expression to Reverse Polish Notation and calculate it. If it is equal to target then return.

My main code is below

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputSubsets.length; i++) {
  const operatorPermutations = getPermutations(
    operators,
    inputSubsets[i].length - 1
  )
  let filteredOperators = []

  let sum = inputSubsets[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

  if (sum < target) {
    filteredOperators = operatorPermutations.filter((perm) => {
      return perm.includes("*")
    })
  } else {
    filteredOperators = operatorPermutations
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < filteredOperators.length; j++) {
    let expression = inputSubsets[i].concat(filteredOperators[j])

    if (permutationHeap(expression, "", target)) {
      const t1 = performance.now()
      console.log(postfixToInfix(validExpression.join(" ")))

      console.log(`Operation lasted : ${(t1 - t0) / 1000} seconds`)
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

I omit the permutations which doesnt include "*" if the sum of the subset is below the target.Which reduced the calculation time 155 seconds to 20-22 seconds. I like to know what i can do to reduce the time more.

Comment: If what you want is a function that given a target number and an arbitraty number of inputs it generates a formula that will get the target number from the other input numbers, then that is way out of scope for a StackOverflow question. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Please show us some code for us to debug, demonstrating your attempt at achieving what you describe here.

Comment: If it's just a matter of doing a homework without learning anything, you can probably find a working code on the web... but not here

Comment: https://datagenetics.com/blog/august32014/index.html

Comment: @eloyra That's exactly what i want. I wish i could show my attempt but honestly i don't know where to start.

Comment: @LaurentS. I don't want the answer i want some way to implement the algorithm

Comment: If you want to hear more suggestions, please edit this to include something of what you've tried, and explain in more detail what you want.  For instance, that is not the only solution.  (`(5 * 50) + 30`).  Are you trying to find *any* such solution or *all* of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you could take two numbers from the inputs array and apply a random operation to them like

```
const plus = ( (a, b) => a + b);
const result1 = plus(inputs[0], inputs[1]);
if(result1 == 280){ console.log("I win!"); }
```

Then try another one, like

```
const times = ( (a, b) => a * b);
const result2 = times(result1, inputs[2]);
```

...And so forth. Eventually with enough processing power, you'd brute force your way through all the combinations.

I'm definitely not saying this is the smartest way, but if you're really just looking for a starting point, then this should help get the brain juices flowing.